# Reduce width of a TH with a "transform:rotated" content to avoid wasted space

Tags: html, css, html-table

I rotated a TH content in order to have a vertical-sided heading for my Table.
Effect is visible here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuCzZ/

Essentially rotation is made through this css:

```
th
{
    width:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

th div
{
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

I would also like to narrow TH width in order to avoid wasted space, but `width:20px` take no effect beacuse is less that width of word "Heading" (I know that `transform:rotate()` has only a "visual effect" but ojects continue to fill original space, something like `position:relative` concept).

Please, how to have TH width reduced to minimum?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: keep the vertical centering of the rotated text in the cell :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vuCzZ/14/)**

*CSS :*

```
td, th {
    border:solid 1px red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
th {
    width:1.6em;
}
th div {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

---

You can use `position: absolute;` and `transform-origin` property :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vuCzZ/2/)**

*CSS :*

```
td, th {
    border:solid 1px red;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
th {
    width:20px;
    position:relative;
}
th div {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-0.6em;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the `bottom:-0.6em;`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla in fact a way to keep the vertical centering in the cell would be a mix between your solution and mine : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vuCzZ/11/ :

Comment: @web-tiki, Thank you for you solution, especially first one. I just updated my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuCzZ/13/)**. It seems that `line-height` and `display:inline-block` are not necessary... :-)

Comment: @LucaDetomi you are right, I think I overlooked that one

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the width to the `div`, not the `th`. The `th` will automatically resize itself:

```
th div
{
    width:20px;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

(note: I need the second transform to make it work on Google Chrome).

A translation then centers the text:

```
th div
{
    width:20px;
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-20px,0);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-20px,0);
}
```

I'm not too happy with this solution because it probably depends on the length of the text.

Comment: @AaronDiguilla, your solution is perfect if is not necessary to center text in cell, due to reasons that you already noted. Anyway, even if not always, in some cases is a very simple and lighweight solution! :-)